# Transforming the position of a placed GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move a cube from A to B. The app I'm working on uses Unity / ARKit to detect a plane. On a touch event it places a cube. This currently works as anticipated.

I now want to transform placed cube to a new position, however my cube is stationary. In the code below, I place the cube. Then, in that `if` statement, I call a method called `MoveToB`, which should get the GameObject called `objectToPlace` and transform it's position. I assume this is where the code is going wrong.

```c#
void Update()
{
    UpdatePlacementPose();
    UpdatePlacementIndicator();

    if (placementPoseIsValid && Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
        PlaceObject();
        Debug.Log("Object Placed"); // This gets called
        MoveToB();
    }
}

private void MoveToB()
{
    objectToPlace.transform.position = new Vector3(100, 100, 100);
    Debug.Log("MoveToB Triggered"); // This gets called
}
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Rest of the code...

```c#
private void PlaceObject()
{
    Instantiate(objectToPlace, placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
}

private void UpdatePlacementIndicator()
{
    if (placementPoseIsValid) {
        placementIndicator.SetActive(true);
        placementIndicator.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
    } else {
        placementIndicator.SetActive(false);
    }
}

private void UpdatePlacementPose()
{
    var screenCentre = Camera.current.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
    var hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
    arOrigin.Raycast(screenCentre, hits, TrackableType.Planes);

    placementPoseIsValid = hits.Count > 0;
    if (placementPoseIsValid) {
        placementPose = hits[0].pose;

        var cameraForward = Camera.current.transform.forward;
        var cameraBearing = new Vector3(cameraForward.x, 0, cameraForward.z).normalized;
        placementPose.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraBearing);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is happening in `PlaceObject`, `UpdatePlacementPose` and `UpdatePlacementIndicator`?

Comment: `PlaceObject` gets `objectToPlace` with `placementPose`'s position and rotation (working as expected). `UpdatePlacementPose` finds planes and stores them in an array if they are valid (working as expected). It then uses the AR camera for position and rotation. `UpdatePlacementIndicator` changes the direction an plane faces based on `UpdatePlacementPose` (working as expected).

Comment: Is `objectToPlace` a prefab?

Answer (score 0):

`objectToPlace` seems to be a prefab?

If that's teue than

```c#
objectToPlace.transform.position = new Vector3(100, 100, 100);
```

tries to translate that prefab, not the object (clone) you Instantiated in your scene.

Instead you should store the reference of placed object

```c#
private GameObject spawnedObject;

private void PlaceObject()
{
  spawnedObject =   Instantiate(objectToPlace, placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
}
```

And than move it

```c#
private void MoveToB()
{
    spawnedObject.transform.position = new Vector3(100, 100, 100);
    Debug.Log("MoveToB Triggered"); // This gets called
}
```